# How to initialize a JSONArray and use in other methods

Tags: java, android, arrays, json, android-volley

I'm going to initialize a JSONArray and set it as input of a method which copies that JSONArray into an ArrayList.

This is my method:

```
    public ArrayList<String> copyJSONArrayToArrayList(JSONArray jArray){
    ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<> ();
    for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
        try {
            arrayList.add(jArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("city"));
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return arrayList;
}
```

and this is my Code:

```
    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, WS_GET_CITY, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            progressbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            try {
                jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("getCity");

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "ERROR", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            progressbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    });

    queue.add(stringRequest);


    ac_srccity = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.ac_srccity);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapterSrc = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, copyJSONArrayToArrayList(jsonArray));
    ac_srccity.setAdapter(adapterSrc);
```

but when I use jsonArray as the method input It says that jsonArray is null !
so I debugged the code and I understood that the sequence of execution is like this:

1.

```
    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
```

2.

```
    queue.add(stringRequest);
```

3.

```
 ac_srccity = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.ac_srccity);
```

4.

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapterSrc = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, copyJSONArrayToArrayList(jsonArray));
```

and in Line 4 the jsonArray is null !

Any Idea !?

Comment: you can do a null check while setting adapter  `if(jsonArray!=null){ArrayAdapter<String> adapterSrc = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, copyJSONArrayToArrayList(jsonArray));
    ac_srccity.setAdapter(adapterSrc);}`  post your json response which will be helpful to look into the issue

Comment: Looks like `jsonObject.getJSONArray("getCity");` is returning null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `JSONArray` isn't being instantiated until you get the callback in `onResponse(String)`, so until your `StringRequest` is finished the `jsonArray` will be `null`.
instead move the inititlization into the callback like so:

```
RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, WS_GET_CITY, new Response.Listener<String>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(String response) {
        progressbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        try {
            jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
            jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("getCity");
            ac_srccity = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.ac_srccity);
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapterSrc = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, copyJSONArrayToArrayList(jsonArray));
            ac_srccity.setAdapter(adapterSrc);

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}, new Response.ErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "ERROR", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        progressbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
});

queue.add(stringRequest);
```

Comment: Yes, it workes, but "this" in Adapter should be "MainActivity.this"

Comment: Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. Hi @AlirezaNoorali if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score -1):

The below code is the answer:

```
RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, WS_GET_CITY, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            progressbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            try {
                jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("getCity");
                ArrayAdapter<String> adapterSrc = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, copyJSONArrayToArrayList(jsonArray));
                ac_srccity.setAdapter(adapterSrc);

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "ERROR", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            progressbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    });

    queue.add(stringRequest);
```